# replot buffer in C, gnuplot issue

Tags: c, gnuplot

I call gnuplot from my C program on a linux system.
I need to plot an ECG data in real time.
I have 6 buffer to fill the gnuplot's window, they don't arrive at the same time.
I need to graficate the first when it arrives in real time(fprintf with points from array and for loop), then when the next buffer arrives I need to maintain the previus and write the next with a second for loop.
But I can't do it. Every time when the next buffer arrives I need to rewrite the previus ones.. It takes in the end 6 for loops(6 buffer to fill the gnuplot's window), and I can't do it because it takes too much time, and in this way I can't get data on the screen in real time.
There's some function in gnuplot to maintain the data written with the previus for loops, and only plot the next??
I hope I've explained myself

this is the previus code I used, every time I need to rewrite the old buffers.

```
while(1) {
    //pulizia buffer e lettura: 4 BUFFER
                      switch(b) {
                      case 0:     
                          bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                          n = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                          if (n < 0) errore("Errore lettura Socket");
                          b = 1;
                          break;
                      case 1:
                      bzero(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
                          n = read(newsockfd, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
                          if (n < 0) errore("Errore lettura Socket");                  
                          b = 2;
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          bzero(buffer3, sizeof(buffer3));
                          n = read(newsockfd, buffer3, sizeof(buffer3));
                          if (n < 0) errore("Errore lettura Socket");
                          b = 3;
                          break;
                      case 3:
                          bzero(buffer4, sizeof(buffer4));
                          n = read(newsockfd, buffer4, sizeof(buffer4));
                          if (n < 0) errore("Errore lettura Socket");
                          b = 0;
                          break;
                      }
    }


    //comunico con gnuplot e invio i miei dati appena letti e caricati sul buffer
    fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' with lines\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    { 
        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", i, buffer[i]); 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    { 
        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", i+256, buffer2[i]); 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    { 
        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", i+512, buffer3[i]); 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    { 
        fprintf(gnuplot, "%d %d\n", i+768, buffer4[i]); 
    } 
    fprintf(gnuplot, "e \n");
```

Comment: Search the documentation for any persistence options. I haven't used this library myself but it sounds like you want the data to persist between multiple writes, then reset on every 6th?

You'll get more useful answers with a code sample we can look at BTW.

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: Gnuplot cannot persist partial data of a single `plot`.

Comment: does anyone have a better and faster idea ? if I save the previus buffer in a .dat file and rewrite them with the next buffer would it be faster than my code  ?

Comment: While gnuplot doesn't keep the _data_ from past plot commands, you could use `set multiplot` to keep the _output_ from previous plot commands, and make additional plots onto the same figure as new data arrives (you might have to fix ranges and margins for that).

Comment: You might also be able to speed things up by sending the data to gnuplot in binary format (right now your code turns data into text, and gnuplot has to parse that to turn it back into data).